# Gradle : Could not download ojdbc7.jar

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I'm trying to run the Gradle project through Intellij. I'm using Gradle 6.6.1 and Java 11 However, I'm getting below error.

```
Could not download ojdbc7.jar (com.oracle:ojdbc7:1.0)
```

Can someone please help? Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Oracle do have a Maven repository of their own, as noted in another answer, they have started using Maven Central as the primary repository for distributing client libraries. They are available under the group name [com.oracle.database.jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc).

If you use Java 11, you don't need the variant of OJDBC for supporting Java 7. Instead, you should use [ojbdc10](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10), which supports both Java 10 and 11. Read more about the different variants of the drivers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/introducing-JDBC.html#GUID-77B9BCB2-BBCC-4862-B02B-5CE1286C997F).

The latest version of ojdbc10 at the time of this writing is [19.7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10/19.7.0.0). It is [certified to work with RDBMS from 11.2 to 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA). So to put it all together, use this dependency declaration in Gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc10:19.7.0.0' // Or 'implementation'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This dependency is available in the oracle maven repository which requires to login. A username and a password are needed that can be acquired by registration to oracle. The repository added should be of the following form:

```
repositories{
//Other repositories...
maven {
    url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"
    name "maven.oracle.com"
    credentials {
       username 'email@mail.com'
       password 'your password'
    }
}
```

}

This information was extracted from [this article](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50484781.shtml).